# JSON post values in particular format and response for login in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to post the data through URl in this format

```
{
    "Authentication": {
      "Username": "test@123",
      "Password": "test@123"
    },
    "RequestType": 7
  }
```

And getting the response value for a particular post value in this format

```
{
StatusCode: 400
StatusMessage: "Order Request Type is Invalid"
}
```

In this how can i validate if status message is equal to Ok then only page redirect to Main Activity otherwise show the alert box. please help me if you have any idea.

Here is my code:

```
  public class MainActivity  extends Activity{
    String oj ;
    String response_value ;
    private  TextView test1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
         // we will using AsyncTask during parsing 
    test1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
       new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();

    }

    // you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

       // contacts JSONArray
       JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {}

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
     // post the  specific format data to json url
           try {
               HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
               object.put("Username", "test@123");
               object.put("Password", "test@123");
               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
               jsonObject.put("Authentication", object);
               jsonObject.put("RequestType", 7);
               HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("Here i pass url");
               postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));
               postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
               postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
               HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              response_value = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return response_value;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String response_value) {
         super.onPostExecute(response_value);
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

            try
            {
             JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response_value); 
            String strStatusMessage=result.optString("StatusMessage");
            if (strStatusMessage.equals("Order Request Type is Invalid")){


Intent ites1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Test.class);
                startActivity(ites1);

            }


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    }
    }
```

Comment: did u try anything ...

Answer (score 0):

> how can i validate if status message is equal to Ok then only page
>   redirect to Main Activity otherwise show the alert box

First get `StatusMessage` message from JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(server_response);
String strStatusMessage=jsonObject.optString("StatusMessage");
```

Now compare `strStatusMessage`  to "ok" :

```
if strStatusMessage equals "ok" Then
  // move to next activity
otherwise
   // show alert
```

Comment: `sry its not working for me` what not working for you because logic is very clear

Comment: @user4536251: In question you have for logic how you do it instead of  why condition is not working are you getting `ok` from server?

Comment: i did small mistake in if condition that's why its not working for me.Now its working.